# c# random operators and math problems, do loop

Tags: c#

Hey guys im trying to work on this assignment i have. I am new to programming and this is my third assignment. Any help would be appreciated. Im not sure if im on the right track or not. here is what i have to do:

allow the user to enter a numeric answer to math problem and display their average score. The user will be allowed to answer as many math problems as they choose. After each entry we will display the current average score. The difference between the while loop and the do loop is the while loop tests a condition before running its code block where the do loop will execute its code block and then test a condition. Hence the names of pre-test loop for the while loop and post-test loop for the do loop. Since the do loop is a post-test loop, it will always execute its code block one time at a bare minimum.

these are the steps im trying to follow:

Inside the Main method block of code we are going to create a do loop. The advantage of a do loop is that it will always execute one time. In this application we will use that advantage to repeat several steps. The following steps are what we want to repeat:

1. Clear the console Display window. (This will keep the display from getting cluttered)
2. Use random object to get/store two random numbers for a math problem.
3. Randomly decide which math operator to use (+-*/)and store the symbol.
4. Display an application header and the math problem formatted.
5. Get the answer from the user and store it in a variable(i.e.“input”).
6. Convert variable(input)from a string to a double or integer.
7. Based on the math symbol calculate the correct answer using random numbers.
8. If user entry matches correct answer,add question point value to points earned total.
9. Add the question point value to the points possible total.
10. Display message with points earned, possible, and the average (earned/possible).
11. Display a message asking the user if they want to quit or get a new math problem.
12. Pause display and get the user response of quit or continue.!

```c#
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MathProblems
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string input;
                double totalPoints = 0;
                double userEarnedPoints = 0;
                double average = 0;
                int number1 = 0;
                int number2 = 0;
                int operators = 0;
                int answer = 0;
                double correctAnswer = 0;
                int mathProblem = 0;

                do
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Random number = new Random();
                    number1 = number.Next(1, 31);
                    number2 = number.Next(1, 31);
                    operators = number.Next(1, 5);  // 1 = add, 2 = minus, 3 = multiply, 4 = divide
                    Console.WriteLine("\tMath Problems\n");

                    switch (operators)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            answer = number1 + number2;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            answer = number1 - number2;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            answer = number1 * number2;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            answer = number1 / number2;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;


                    }
                    //if (operators == 1)
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = ", number1, number2);

                    //}
                    //else if (operators == 2)
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = ", number1, number2);
                    //}
                    //else if (operators == 3)
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = ", number1, number2);
                    //}
                    //else if (operators == 4)
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = ", number1, number2);
                    //}
                    //break;


                } while (true);

                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I'd say yes, you're on the right track.  `answer` probably needs to be a `double` to handle division, e.g., 7 / 2.

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `Random` in a loop - that's a bad idea. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx Now, what is your exact question? You've provided your assignment and what you've done so far, but we need to know exactly what you're asking. Where are you stuck?

Comment: You can also store the string representation of the operator in the existing switch-case and use that in the formatted output.

Comment: `Push Random = new Random();` out of the loop; ask user if (s)he wants to continue the process and modify `while (true)` into `while (wants_to_continue)` condition

Comment: Im just not sure what to do next. when i run it, it keeps posting "math problems" over and over and not generating the actual math problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get user input, you need to do `Console.ReadKey()` (for a single character) or `Console.ReadLine()` (for a string of characters terminated by `Enter`). You can then capture this input in a variable and then do a comparison on it to get the user's answer or to determine if they want to continue or not.

You also will need to validate that the input was an integer. You can use int.TryParse() to do this. It will return true if the string was an integer, and will store the integer in the `out` parameter.

You can then compare the userAnswer to the actual answer to see if they got it right. It also looks like you need to increment the total problems and the user score (when they get an answer correct)

One way to do this would be:

```
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var quit = false;
    var userScore = 0;
    var totalProblems = 0;
    var percentCorrect = 0d;

    while (!quit)
    {
        Console.Clear();

        var number1 = rnd.Next(1, 31);
        var number2 = rnd.Next(1, 31);
        var operation = rnd.Next(1, 5);            
        string operatorString;
        int answer;
        totalProblems++;

        Console.WriteLine("\tMath Problem:");
        Console.WriteLine("\t-------------");

        switch (operation)
        {
            case 1:
                answer = number1 + number2;
                operatorString = "+";
                break;
            case 2:
                answer = number1 - number2;
                operatorString = "-";
                break;
            case 3:
                answer = number1 * number2;
                operatorString = "*";
                break;
            case 4:
                answer = number1 / number2;
                operatorString = "/";
                break;
            default:
                answer = 0;
                operatorString = "?";
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} {1} {2}", number1, operatorString, number2);

        Console.Write("\nEnter your answer here (round down if necessary): ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        int inputAsInt;

        while (!int.TryParse(input, out inputAsInt))
        {
            Console.Write("Answer must be an integer. Try again: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (inputAsInt == answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            userScore++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the correct answer was: {0}", answer);
        }

        percentCorrect = Math.Round((double)userScore / totalProblems * 100, 2);

        Console.WriteLine("\nYou have answered {0} of {1} questions correctly, " +
            "for a total of {2}%.", userScore, totalProblems, percentCorrect);

        Console.Write("\nPress 'q' to quit, or any other key to continue... ");
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Q) quit = true;
    }

    var letterGrade =
        percentCorrect < 60 ? "F"
        : percentCorrect < 67 ? "D"
        : percentCorrect < 70 ? "D+"
        : percentCorrect < 73 ? "C-"
        : percentCorrect < 77 ? "C"
        : percentCorrect < 80 ? "C+"
        : percentCorrect < 83 ? "B-"
        : percentCorrect < 87 ? "B"
        : percentCorrect < 90 ? "B+"
        : percentCorrect < 93 ? "A-"
        : "A";

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nThank you for playing. You've earned you a letter " +
        "grade of: {0}", letterGrade);
    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: @kegs88 Not sure if this answers your question or not?